Rectangle-like structures and their folding in physics
It is well known that mathematics helps to explain some science problems. For example gömböc, which was a well hidden body from mathematicians, explains the body structure of some tortoises in relation to their ability to return to an equilibrium position after being placed upside down.
First of all, my question is an attempt to find an analogous application for a very special rectangle in physics:
There exists a unique rectangle with sides $a$ and $b$, where $a$ less $b$, with two ways of being folded along a line through its center such that the area of overlap is minimized and each area yields a different shape – a triangle and a pentagon. The unique ratio of side lengths is $\frac {a} {b}=0.8150237...$
The special rectangle is like a bistable structure with some minimum of overlapping and folding angles: $45^\circ$ and $\approx 24.66^\circ$ (for over ratio of sides there is just one folding angle: for eg. 'long rectangle'(like a strip of paper) is always folded at $45^\circ$).
Any ideas where the property may appear in physics are highly welcomed.
In addition to that (suppose it's hard to answer #1), do you think it's possible to set an experiment  which show the existence of the 'bistable structure' with some minimum of overlapping like for the special rectangle?
(more details about folding rectangle and pictures in OEIS: Folding rectangle )


This really is math problem rather than a physics problem, perhaps Mathematics would be better suited for this.

Yes, it's from math, but I'd like to find analogue or application for the special rectangle in physics. This is why I decided to post here
